SFTP server on Linux (Debian)
I'm new here and looking for help or tips. I've just set my SFTP server on linux, Debian. I've used some tutorials on the internet. It says that I have to do like this:
useradd -g sftp -d /home/sftp -s /sbin/nologin username
mkdir -p /home/sftp/username/files
chmod 500 /home/sftp
chmod 700 /home/sftp/username/files
chown root:sftp /home/sftp/username
chown username:sftp /home/sftp/username/files

Then I have to make changes in sshd:
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO

and on the end:
Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home/sftp/%u
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp

Everything seems to be fine. SFTP server works. But there's one small problem: this server is allowed to make one user per one folder. It means: I can't add more than one user to one folder! I can't make it work but my customer wants to do this :-( Is there any way to make it to add more than one user?

Can't you use unix groups for that?

(this should be a comment, but space is limited in the box above)

But there's one small problem: this server is allowed to make one user per one folder. It means: I can't add more than one user to one folder!

You explain your assertion by repeating your assertion. And neither time does it make a lot of sense. Reading between the lines a LOT here, it seems you are attempting to create some sort of shared network folder.
Generally the first step in solving a problem in IT is to define the problem, then design the solution, then implement the solution. You have jumped straight to the final step.
Who are the people who will be access this service?
Are you content to provide a free-for-all service where any user can delete or modify any other user's files?
If you don't want to restrict access for any of the users, then your issue is probably due to the permissions on the home directory and any directories created within it. Setting g+rwx on the directory + any sub-directory and g+rw on any files will allow shared access, but any new files/directories created will have the original, restricted permissions; you need to set the umask to change this. It looks like you are using OpenSsh-server, in which case...
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO -u 002

